# uncaught syntaxerror invalid regular expression flags

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy haciendo un modal para dos funciones distintas crear y actualizar la idea es que hallan dos botones el de crear un nuevo registro se muestre el modal con los campos vacíos para crear el nuevo registro el id es auto incrementable y el otro es el de actualizar el registro este botón va a estar en la columna acciones junto a el de eliminar y cada registro debe tener estos dos botones la idea que al oprimir el botón de actualizar abra el modal con los datos del registro del usuario que se desea actualizar

```js
@section scripts {
    <script>
        var tabladata;
        var filaseleccionada;
        
        tabladata = $("#tabla").DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            ordering: false,
            "ajax": {
                url: @Url.Action("listarUsuarios", "Home"),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
                
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Nombres" },
                { "data": "Apellidos" },
                { "data": "Correo" },
                {
                    "data": "Activo", "render": function (valor) {
                        if (valor) {

                            return '<span class="badge bg-success">si</span>'
                        } else {
                            return '<span class="badge bg-danger">no</span>'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    //este codigo es el de actualizar
                    "defaultContent": ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-editar"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ms-2"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width":"90px"
                }
            ]
        });
        $("#cargar").click(function abrirModal(data) {
            $("txtid").val(0);
            $("txtNombre").val("");
            $("txtApellido").val("");
            $("txtCorreo").val("");
            $("cboactivo").val(1);

            if (data != null) {
                $("txtid").val(IdUsuario);
                $("txtNombre").val(data.Nombres);
                $("txtApellido").val(data.Apellidos);
                $("txtCorreo").val(data.Correo);
                $("cboactivo").val(data.Activo == true ? 1 : 0);
            }

            $("#formModal").modal("show");
        });

        $("#tabla tbody").on("click", '.btn-editar', function () {
            filaseleccionada = $(this).closest("tr");
            var data = tabladata.row(filaseleccionada).data();
            abrirModal(data)
            
        })

        function guardar() {

            var Usuario = {
                IdUsuario: $("#txtid").val(),
                Activo: $("#cboactivo").val() == 1 ? true : false,
                Apellidos: $("#txtApellido").val(),
                Correo: $("#txtCorreo").val(),
                Nombres: $("txtNombre")
            }

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: @Url.Action("GuardarUsurio", "Home"),
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ objeto: Usuario}),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json chartset-utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                    debugger;
                    //usuario nuevo
                    if (Usuario.IdUsuario == 0) {
                        if (data.IdUsuario != 0) {

                            Usuario.IdUsuario = data.resultado;
                            tabladata.row.add(Usuario).draw(false);
                            $("#modal1").modal("hide");
                        } else {
                            alert(data.mensaje)
                        }
                       
                    } else {
                        tabladata.row(filaseleccionada).data(Usuario).draw(false);
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                },
                beforeSend: function () {

                }
            });


            
        }
    </script>

    
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="formModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
              <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="tituloModal1">nuevo registro</h1>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body g-2">
                <input id="txtid" type="hidden" value="0"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="txtNombre" class="form-label">nombres</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombre" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="txtApellido" class="form-label">apellidos</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtApellido" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="txtCorreo" class="form-label">correo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCorreo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="cboactivo" class="form-label">activo</label>
                        <select id="cboactivo" class="form-select">
                            <option value="1">si</option>
                            <option value="0">no</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guardar()">guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```